# Identify item that triggered run a script code in a rule

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to export the contents of any email that is received to a text file automatically. If there is text already in that text file, then the new text should overwrite it.

A rule can be made to run this script when an email is received.

For example:
I receive an email that says "Happy Birthday".

The text "Happy Birthday" should be saved to "incomingEmail.txt"

```
Sub extractDataAsString(item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim sText As String

    Set olItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection.item(1)
    sText = olItem.Body

    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim Fileout As Object
    Set Fileout = fso.CreateTextFile("K:\Project\Python\incomingEmail.txt", True, True)
    Fileout.Write sText
    Fileout.Close

End Sub
```

The code above exports the currently selected e-mail's body to the text file. I want to export the body of the new e-mail to the text file.

I think this is because of the line:

```
Set olItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection.item(1)
```

However, I can't find how to select the latest e-mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The item that triggers run a script code is passed to the code. There is no need to find it again.

```
Sub RunAScript_code(item As Outlook.MailItem)

    MsgBox "The item that triggered this code is: " & item.subject

End Sub
```